# updating replicated array on node js cluster

Tags: node.js, memcached

I was wondering how one could constantly update across all machines in node js cluster, in an efficient manner. Would memcached be a better solution here? I ask because I want to know if I can have, lets say 5 different machines, access a fairly large associative array that gets manipulated frequently. So I wanted to know if replicating it across the 5 machines in their own memory pool would be better and then just update all when one is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the data with NodeJS, then you should look at [Redis](http://redis.io/). It can be easily replicated across different machines.

Generally the problem you are facing is not an easy one and there is no universal (efficient) solution, because of [the CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Comment: could there be a way the 5 different machines could have access to a shared memory pool?

Comment: Well, not physically. But there are ways to emulate such behaviour without losing efficiency. That's where Redis comes.